# Distributing Debian packages from Django project via stdeb

Tags: python, django, package, debian

Does anyone know a **really good, full, understandable and useful instructions** on how to create a Debian package of a **Django** project via stdeb?

Answer (score 0):

May be you'll find [this](https://hynek.me/articles/python-app-deployment-with-native-packages/) helpful. Author uses fpm to build deb packages, not stdeb, but I used his ideas for about a year to deploy my projects and completely satisfied with it.